# Solve the $5^{45} \pmod{2017}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to find solutions of $5^{45} \pmod{2017}?$

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you compute $5^5 \pmod{2017}$ (or type your query into WolframAlpha verbatim)?

Comment: Sorry , I don't know how to approach this problem

Comment: Did you try my suggestion of computing $5^5$?

Comment: Yes I have $5^5=3125$ and  so we have $5^5 \mod{2017}=1108$

Comment: Then $5^{10}$ (square modulo $2017$), $5^{20}$, $5^{40}$, $5^{45}$.

Answer (score 2):

I call this method "divide and conquer." Notice that $n^2 \pmod{m} \equiv (n \pmod{m} * n \pmod{m}) \pmod{m}.$

So $5^{4} \equiv 25 * 25 \pmod{2017};$

$5^{8} \equiv 625 * 625 \pmod{2017} \equiv 1344 \pmod{2017};$

$5^{16} \equiv 1344 * 1344 \pmod{2017} \equiv 1121 \pmod{2017};$

$5^{32} \equiv 1121 * 1121 \pmod{2017} \equiv 50 \pmod{2017}.$

Now we want to get $13$ more powers of $5,$ which we can do by multiplying $5 * 5^{4} * 5^{8}.$ This yields a remainder of $606$ when divided by $2017$ (use modular multiplications on the powers we found earlier). Our final answer is $50 * 606 \pmod{2017} \equiv \boxed{45} \pmod{2017}.$

Comment: You should try to refrain from answering low quality questions in great detail. Providing hints and constructive questions in the comments should suffice.